# Insert script tag in a Ember template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-cli

Is it possible to insert script tag in a Ember template (i.e. hbs file)
I want the following script tag to be rendered inside my page. if not in hbs template, how  can I do that in my Ember app ?

```
<script language="javascript">

var x= '-----BEGINCERT-----

-----END CERT-----\n;';
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that variable? If you just want to set a global, you can also write to `window.x` in your route or controller.

Comment: It is needed in the rendered html output by some 3rd party tool

Comment: You definitely shouldn't place script tag in ember templates. Can you tell us what 3rd party tool you're using and what are you trying to achieve with that var.

Answer (score 1):

Script tags are explicitly not allowed in Ember templates. There's an [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12935) that discusses this on GitHub. If you're trying to set a global variable you could do as suggested in the comments and set the value from code. Alternatively you could add the script to the index.html of your app.